# Notepad++ Explorer plugin

Tags: plugins, explorer, notepad++

I'm currently using the notepad++ as my code editor..since it was so quick to start i'm pretty much like this..but i have a problem regarding the explorer plugin..i can't add the network drive so that i can access the shared document from other workstation. only the drive C and D showed up. How to show the network drive in the explorer plugin?

Comment: I think this belongs on Super User.

Comment: When you say 'explorer plugin', you may want to specified which plugin and version you use. eg/ 'Light Explorer 2.0

Comment: I'm using the Explorer 1.8.2(UNI).

Comment: I am using windows 7 and neither plugin shows network drives

Answer (score 9):

The explorer plugin won't show a mapped network drive, but the light explorer plugin will. Both of these are available in the plugin manager.

EDIT: I answered this extremely old question because it is the top Google result for this search, so it may as well have the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Light Explorer plugin.

By mapping your network drive with a drive letter, that should show up in the explorer tree.